# Mostrar colores tomados de una base de datos php

Tags: php, mysql, color

Tengo una aplicación web, la cual tiene un formulario para el registro de nuevos usuarios; a cada usuario se le asigna un color único, tomado de la `BD (MySQL)`.

Tengo una tabla usuarios y una tabla colores, teniendo dos usuarios registrados quiero que al mostrar la tabla de usuarios me muestre el color asignado a cada usuario; hasta el momento he logrado que muestre el código hexadecimal del color, que es el guardado en la `BD`.

¿Alguien sabe leer ese código y mostrar el color en la celda?

```
<?php
    $tusers = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN cat_niveles n ON u.Nivel=n.id LEFT JOIN cat_centros c ON u.ID_CC=c.id LEFT JOIN cat_colores k ON u.id_color=k.id");
    $listU = $tusers->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($listU); $i++) { 
        echo '<tr>';    
        echo "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['User']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['nombre_nivel']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre_CC']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Fecha_Registro']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['has_color']."</td>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Puedes simplemente aplicarlo como fondo de la celda añadiendo el estilo, ejemplo `'<td style="background-color:'.$listU[$i]['has_color'].'">'.$listU[$i]['has_color'].'</td>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así debería de funcionar. Solo tienes que poner el color en una etiqueta `style`, con la propiedad `background-color`.

```
<?php
    $tusers = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN cat_niveles n ON u.Nivel=n.id LEFT JOIN cat_centros c ON u.ID_CC=c.id LEFT JOIN cat_colores k ON u.id_color=k.id");
    $listU = $tusers->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($listU); $i++) { 
        echo '<tr>';    
        echo "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['User']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['nombre_nivel']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre_CC']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Fecha_Registro']."</td>".
            "<td style='background-color: #.$listU[$i]['has_color']. ;'>""</td>";  
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

supongo que deseas algo así:

```
<?php
    $tusers = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM user u LEFT JOIN cat_niveles n ON u.Nivel=n.id LEFT JOIN cat_centros c ON u.ID_CC=c.id LEFT JOIN cat_colores k ON u.id_color=k.id");
    $listU = $tusers->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($listU); $i++) { 
        echo '<tr>';    
        echo "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['User']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['nombre_nivel']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Nombre_CC']."</td>".
            "<td>".$listU[$i]['Fecha_Registro']."</td>".
            "<td><div style='width:20px;height:20px;background-color:".$listU[$i]['has_color']."'></div></td>";
    }
?>
```

si el código no contiene el # solo debes agregarlo en caso contrario dejar así.

Comment: Sos un genio, probé de mil maneras y no había modo.
¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada para ello es esta comunidad =)